# How to do a simple subquery in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm a newbie in SQLAlchemy and haven't got much chance to deal with subqueries. I'm using Flask SQLAlchemy, for the record.

Below is the first part of the query:

```
Team.query.filter(Team.season_id==12610)
```

Below is the part I'd like to query the first part with: (If that is even possible)

```
Team.query.order_by(desc(Team.team_rank))
```

Basically, after filtering from a certain `season_id`, I want to to order the teams by `team_rank`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there! Just chain the commands.

```
from sqlalchemy import desc
Team.query.filter(Team.season_id == 12610).order_by(desc(Team.team_rank))
```